# Is there a simple way to implement "pretty link" in Django-CMS, similar to the WordPress Pretty Links plugin?

Tags: django

I'm planning to build a website using Django-CMS, and plan to include affiliate links, which I want to cloak, i.e. have mysite.com/rec-product redirect to affiliate-site.com/product-with-affiliate-info, preferably with the mapping stored in the database.

Is there a simple way to implement "pretty links" in Django-CMS, similar to the WordPress Pretty Links plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with a redirects application by default: [`django.contrib.redirects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/redirects/). It allows you to add redirects via the Django admin interface or using the Django database API.

It looks like someone has adapted this to be integrated with Django CMS: [django-cms-redirects](https://github.com/salvaorenick/django-cms-redirects).